# What does function($) mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realize that the $ is just sort of a convention for naming variables pointing to jQuery objects, and is also the function for document.getElementById(), but does function($) mean anything?

Edit: I actually meant

```
(function($) {
    /* ... */
})(jQuery);
```

Sorry for the confusion, but thanks for the answers.

Comment: Just `function ( $ )` is not a complete statement, so it means nothing...

Comment: I found the following link useful as well: http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/jQueryPluginTutorial_Beginner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some code uses $ for jQuery (or other libraries) to keep the global scope clean.  By default, jQuery takes over $ in the global scope, however, if extensions and whatnot avoid using the global $, it can keep the scope clean, along with helping jQuery work with other libraries.

```
(function ($) {
    //$ is now a jquery instance
})(jQuery);
```

Basically it's a way to instantly execute code with a jQuery object without the function depending on a global-level variable.  (Closures can also be created with it...  But that's the same idea [in this situation].)

Answer (score 4):

`function($)` is an anonymous function that receives the jQuery object as it's sole parameter (of course, you would expect it to be followed by an implementation within `{}` blocks).

Comment: $ is a shortcut in many other JavaScript frameworks as well. In this case, it's simply a method parameter. Doesn't necessarily refer to a framework at all.

Comment: True, although `$` is most commonly used for jQuery (and the OP mentions jQuery in his post)

Answer (score 2):

It's an anonymous function that takes a single parameter named `$`.