# What does function($) mean?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning JavaScript. Found a statement `function($) { ...}` while checking out examples. Can anyone tell me what `function($)` means?

Comment: See javascript clouser's. Keep in mind that **java !=javascript**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341265/what-does-function-mean-in-javascript

Comment: `function($)` means that you are defining a function whose first argument will be bound to the identifier `$`, which is just another identifier, no special semantics.

Comment: You can see a nice example here on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/what-does-function-jquery-mean This will give a good understanding of what it does. Check this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "This defines a function. When it is called: create a local variable called `$` and assign the value of the first argument to it."

Answer (score 0):

**First off:** This creates a function where `$` is the first argument passed to it. It could look like this potentially:

```
function dollar($){
    alert($);
}

dollar("hello")
//alerts "hello"
```

Typically this is used when you want the `$` to mean `jQuery`.

For example:

```
(function($){
    //stuff where $ === jQuery
})(jQuery)
```

Means that jQuery will be passed into the `$` variable for the scope of anything that happens in that function.

This can be useful if you have multiple libraries within the global scope that *may* use the `$` variable, but you have a modular plugin that refers to the necessary library as that and you don't want to rewrite the whole thing.

**Note:** It does not always mean `jQuery` but in about 80% of cases it will. Otherwise it is just a convenient way to bind a library to a shorter variable within a certain scope.